# Swipe method not working in android automation testing

Tags: android, testing, automation, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to implement swipe method.May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

```
public void swipeWithCordinateLocation(WebDriver driver,double startX,
                                       double  startY,double endX,double endY,
                                       double Duration)
{
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, Double> swipeObject = new HashMap<String, Double>();
swipeObject.put("x", startX);
swipeObject.put("y", startY);
swipeObject.put("x", endX);
swipeObject.put("y",endY );
swipeObject.put("duration", Duration);
// HashMap[] param = {swipeObject};
js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", swipeObject);

}

common.swipeWithCordinateLocation(driver, 100.00, 500.00, 500.00, 500.00, 1.00);
```

But appium is perform swipe but it takes different credentials

```
[x=360][y=592]
 to [x=360][y=592]
```

. what to do?
Can any one help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to analyze a swipe in automation is to enable "Show touches" and "pointer location" options in your developer option.

The correct code for the swipe parameters is this -

```
swipeObject.put("startX", 198.00);
swipeObject.put("startY", 685.00);
swipeObject.put("endX", 198.00);
swipeObject.put("endY", 550.00);
swipeObject.put("duration", 1.0);
```

Hope this helps.

Or even a better way is to use something like using fractions -

```
swipeObject.put("startX", 0.50);
swipeObject.put("startY", 0.50);
swipeObject.put("endX", 0.50);
swipeObject.put("endY", 0.35);
swipeObject.put("duration", 1.0);
```

Comment: It need to import any JAR file to support swipeObject?

Comment: this answer is for an older version of appium.New version uses a AppiumClient Jar

Comment: Okay..I will download and use that jar.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use swipe() of AppiumDriver as shown below:

Swipe Left:

```
 public void swipeLeft()
  {
      AppiumDriver appiumDriver = (AppiumDriver) driver;
      appiumDriver.context("NATIVE_APP"); 
      Dimension size = appiumDriver.manage().window().getSize(); 
      int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.8); 
      int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.20); 
      int starty = size.height / 2; 
      appiumDriver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 1000);

  }
```

Swipe Right:

```
 public void swipeRight()
  {
      AppiumDriver appiumDriver = (AppiumDriver) driver;
      appiumDriver.context("NATIVE_APP"); 
      Dimension size = appiumDriver.manage().window().getSize(); 
      int endx= (int) (size.width * 0.8); 
      int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.20); 
      int starty = size.height / 2; 
      appiumDriver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 1000);

  }
```

Comment: Your swipeLeft() and swipeRight() method coordinates are same. How it those methods differentiate between left and right?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same swiping result with TouchAction

```
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(androidDriver);
    action.press(0, 500)
            .waitAction(200)
            .moveTo(0, 200)
            .release()
            .perform();
```

Just play with the coordinates to get the desidered swiping.

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use uiautomator for the same .
It will help you to automate test cases very effectively and faster.

you can read more about it at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html