# Appium MobileElement swipe returns unknown server error

Tags: selenium, appium

I am trying to swipe MobileElement but its giving server-side error. What may be the cause here?

code :

```
 MobileElement mb= (MobileElement)driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[@index='0'][@resource-id='android:id/list']"));

 mb.swipe(SwipeElementDirection.LEFT, 1000);
```

**Error :**

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not
>   provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 16
>   milliseconds

Comment: you can also use TouchAction class to swipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try with this piece of code for dynamic swipe for all the mobile devices:**

```java
Dimension dimension = driver.manage().window().getSize();
int width = dimension.getWidth();
int height = dimension.getHeight();
switch(direction) {
    case "right":
        driver.swipe((int) (width*(0.20)), (int) (height*(0.50)), (int)(width*(0.80)), (int) (height*(0.50)), 6000);
    break;
    case "left":
        driver.swipe((int) (width*(0.80)), (int) (height*(0.50)), (int) (width*(0.20)), (int) (height*(0.50)), 6000);
    break;
    case "up":
        driver.swipe((int) (width*(0.50)), (int) (height*(0.70)), (int) (width*(0.50)), (int) (height*(0.30)), 6000);
    break;
    default:
        driver.swipe((int) (width*(0.50)), (int) (height*(0.30)), (int) (width*(0.50)), (int) (height*(0.70)), 6000);
    break;
}
```

Comment: I have written code for "scroll Up" and it ends when it finds specific string in the bottom. 
I wanted to know is there any specif way to know if its end of page (without comparing b/w elements etc)

Comment: Nope currently in appium there no method that will stop the scroll when it's end of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, this will work:

```java
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);

int startY2 = element1.getLocation().getY() + (element.getSize().getHeight() / 2);

int startX2 = element1.getLocation().getX() + (element.getSize().getWidth() / 2);

int endX2 = element2.getLocation().getX() + (element2.getSize().getWidth() / 2);

int endY2 = element2.getLocation().getY() + (element2.getSize().getHeight() / 2) - (element2.getSize().getHeight()/2);


action.press(startX2, startY2).waitAction(2000).moveTo(endX2, endY2).release().perform();
```

Comment: @Divya, if you found the answer helpful  - please accept it. If you don't know how, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Using AppiumDriver its better to implement this in your base class

```
public void swipe(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy, int duration)
```

Call it as :

```
driver.swipe((int)screenWidth(), (int)screenHeight()*0.6), (int)screenWidth(), (int)screenHeight()*0.4), 0);
```